# Is it possible to have very different sea levels?

Tags: ocean, waterfall

This image demonstrates what I'm trying to do. Basically the ocean "drops" down to a lower level via a waterfall, with different sea levels, sort of like how we have "locks" on our rivers. Is there any way this could be possible, or is it just too far out there?

[image]

You can't see a bottom in the image, but in my idea, there is another ocean way down there, and a massive "wall" leading up to the higher ocean. I'm not sure if water can circulate in this way, but maybe evaporation could constantly redistribute it as it falls down.

Comment: Wouldn't the upper one lose all its salt and become a lake rather than sea - given sufficient time? WHat sort of time-scale are you looking at?

Comment: @Sam Moon with out magic no it is impossible. The water on the upper edge would just drain. But if you have multiple oceans completely cut off from one another than yeah they can have different sea levels. But as you have shown it it's impossible.

Answer (score 20):

An example on smaller scale of what you want can be seen at the Bøsdalafossur waterfall, in the Faroe Islands.

[image]

However in that case it's a lake forming the waterfall in the ocean, not an ocean.

Something similar involving oceans has happened in the past when the Gibraltar strait opened up again and the Atlantic started falling down into the dried up Mediterranean sea, during the Messinian salinity crisis.

And I believe that's the only way in which it can happen in your case: a transitory phenomena, when an ocean pours down in a water deprived region until it fills it.

Answer (score 16):

This has happened already multiple times in geological history. For example, the Mediterranean dried up multiple times and then refilled. Likewise, the Black Sea used to be a deep valley with a lake and then the Bosphorus opened up. When the Atlantic Ocean first started opening up, it was significantly lower. At present, the Atlantic Ocean is about 20 cm lower than the Pacific. https://psmsl.org/train_and_info/faqs/#3

Large differences are always "temporary" but can last for years. They happen when the land to be filled sinks first and then opens to the ocean. The speed at which they fill up depends on the size of the opening to the rest of the world's oceans.

Comment: The opening to the rest of the world will deepen rapidly. Catastrophic flood events (of which there are many in the geological record) erode rock at enormous rates; the rate at which the base of the channel drops is faster than the rate at which the level of the surface of the ocean drops, so you get a runaway process (until things are mostly equalized).

Answer (score 12):

## This is Impossible

The equation is simple: water lost to the "lower ocean" must be replaced by rainfall (if we assume no magic).

If the waterfall is not limited to a very, very small area (and the upper ocean is otherwise bounded), you would effectively need a waterfall's worth of water constantly falling on the upper tier.

Answer (score 3):

On Earth, we have one big body of water, commonly known as "the Ocean" which covers most of the surface and a number of smaller bodies of water, usually called lakes.

These smaller bodies of water can be above or below the Ocean, and this difference is maintained because water evaporates in one place, moves with the wind and rains down somewhere else.  Weather can move big amounts of water.

Often there will be rivers moving the water back where it came from and they can have spectacular waterfalls.

If we move to another planet, there is nothing stopping you from saying there are multiple really big bodies of water.

On Earth, most of the planets surface is covered with water.  This leads naturally to one big ocean with multiple continents.  On a drier planet, where less than half of the surface is ocean, you will naturally get one big landmass, with multiple big bodies of water, possibly continent-sized.

Weather can move water from one to another to give the water level difference you want.

As Donal Fellows notes in a comment to [another answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/256827/10324), waterfalls cause erosion, so the city in your image would not last very long.

To counteract this erosion, your planet will need to be geologially active,
with continental plates moving around making mountains and such. (Like Earth)